# Position Chosen select box choices on top of select box without auto-selecting the first option

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, jquery-chosen

I have been trying with no success to position the choices of a Chosen select box over top of the select box itself without automatically selecting the first option when the select box is initially clicked.

Here is a JSFiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/sdrah3g7/

And here is how I would like to position the choices via css:

```
.chosen-container .chosen-drop {
top: 0 !important;
}
```

I have a feeling that this could be solved by modifying the Chosen JS file to create a delay between when the select box is clicked and when its elements may be selected, or maybe by disabling the selection of choices until after the mouse button has been released from the initial clicking of the select box.

Unfortunately, my knowledge of JavaScript at this point is quite limited and the lack of commenting in the Chosen code is making it difficult for me to approach the issue. I will continue to attempt to solve the issue, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Removing `top: 0 !important;` works as desired. I think what happens is click is getting registered when you click the input box and results in first dropdown automatic pick.

Comment: @Rikin Thanks, but the `top: 0;` is necessary to the design of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/sdrah3g7/1/

I changed chosen code a bit.

Instead of `onmouseup` I set `onmousedown` function where it was needed.

```
this.search_results.bind('mousedown.chosen', function(evt) { // mouseup to mousedown
    _this.search_results_mousedown(evt); // this function call changed to mousedown and function name also
});
```

Code is changed on:
- lines 684, 685 - this is code above
- line 967 - function name
- line 525 - function call for touch events

You can download changed chosen script [here](http://w3adventures.com/download/js/chosen.jquery.mousedown.js)

Comment: Thanks so much! It makes sense why it was doing that now. I appreciate the help.